# Sencha: How to call a method/function on a model, not its record instance?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I would like to call a method on a Model, not on an instance of the model. How can I do that?

I currently have the following, which does not work:

```
var Setting = Ext.ModelManager.getModel('MyApp.model.Setting');
Setting.setCode('asdf');
```

It gives me `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

My Model is:

```
Ext.define("MyApp.model.Setting", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Model",
    config: {
        fields: [
            { name: 'someCode', type: 'string' },
         ],
    },

    setCode(c){
        console.log('yey ');
        // Save the settings
    }
});
```

Apparently, I can create an record instance of setting, and run the function on it, but that is not what I am interested in, I want to execute the model method. If anyone knows how to do that, please let me know.

Answer (score -1):

```
Setting.prototype.setCode('abc')
```

Comment: Could you explain briefly why this would fix the problem?